# Is there a function formulating bounding values?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

Need to find a mathematical operation formulating such a function:

```
a<=x<=b,-r<=w<=r,r<b-a
y=x+w, if a<=x+w<=b;
y=b,   if x+w>b;
y=a,   if x+w<a;
```

[image]

This is just similar to [mod operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). So is there an operation for the above function?

Comment: I think the flags operator-theory and mathematical-physics should be deleted.

Comment: $y = \min(\max(x+\omega,a),b)$. Some people simply called this a clamp function, especially in the special case $a = 0, b = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is equivalent to

$$\frac{a + b + |x+\omega - a| - |x+\omega - b|}{2}$$

where $| \cdot |$ denotes [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

---

You can see an [example of this function in action, with $a = 5$ and $b=7$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(+5+%2B+7+%2B+%7C+y+-+5+%7C+-+%7C+y+-+7+%7C+)+%2F+2).

I've substituted $y=x+\omega$ in the wolfram alpha demostration to make it easier to see the behavior of the function. As someone has pointed out in the comments, these types of functions are examples of [clamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)).